# RegExp with included and excluded symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate user input.

All English letters and symbols ".","-","&","'", "&" are allowed. Other symbols aren't allowed.

I have next RegExp which work for string "fffц":

```
var myRegExp = new RegExp("[a-z]+","ig")
myRegExp.test("fffц") // return false
```

But it doesn't work with string "fffцfff":

```
var myRegExp = new RegExp("[a-z]+","ig")
myRegExp.test("fffцfff") // return true, but string contains Russian letters, I expected false
```

How to write the correct regular expression?

Comment: Both of the example regexen you've provided return `true` for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `[a-z]+` which means "match at least once alphabetic character anywhere."  You need to be using anchors

```
^[a-z.& '-]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would allow only  english alphabets,numbers and sepcial characters.

```
var myRegExp = new RegExp("[ -~]+","ig")
```